# Bayesian network and conditional probability tables

Tags: probability, bayesian, bayesian-networks

(Detecting pregnancy based on three tests)The  first  is  a  scanning  testwhich has a false positive of 1% and a false negative of 10%.  The second is a blood test, whichdetects  progesterone  with  a  false  positive  of  10%  and  false  negative  of  30%.   The  third  is  aurine test,  which also detects  progesterone with a  false positive of  10% and a  false negative of20%.  The  probability  of  a  detectable  progesterone  level  is  90%  given  pregnancy,  and  1%  givenno  pregnancy.  The  probability  of  pregnancy  after  two  positive  tests  is  0.364%.  Construct  theBayesian network and specify the conditional probability tables.

[image]

This is the bayesian netwirk that i've tried to make. The only question is how do i calculate the pregnancy: P(pregnancy). I tried to calculate like this based on the text:P(pregnancy| blood,urine V blood,scanning V scanning,urine V scanning,scanning, V urine,urine V blood,blood) but it will give a too complicated formula and maybe there's an easier way to do this. I know all the probabilities from the bayesian network except the pregnancy one.

Comment: Since this is a conceptual question, it's off topic here; try stats.stackexchange.com instead. That said, bear in mind that P(pregnancy) represents your degree of belief about pregnancy in the absence of any other information. So P(pregnancy) is not something that can be derived from blood, urine, or scanning. In the absence of any of the test results, what is your degree of belief? That is what you need to put into P(pregnancy).

Comment: @RobertDodier is there a reason why you didn't close vote with migrate to CV?